# Is it possible to set the ACTION property of a form so upon submit() it does not add a leading slash to the request?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My form looks like this:

```js
<form name="JRBHSO" method=POST action="/WEBSO.CGI" onSubmit="return clickstrt()" autocomplete="off" >
```

What is sent upon submission looks like this:

```
POST /WEBSO.CGI HTTP/1.1.....
```

The request is to make it look like this to the server (upon submission) :
(remove the leading slash)

```
POST WEBSO.CGI HTTP/1.1.....
```

Changing the `action` to the following does not prevent the leading slash... the browser (Chrome in this case) adds the leading slash.

```js
<form name="JRBHSO" method=POST action="WEBSO.CGI" onSubmit="return clickstrt()" autocomplete="off" >
```

I have also attempted to modify the `action` property dynamically using JavaScript but it still persists on adding the leading slash.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Actually this is a normal behavior.
What exactly you trying to do?

Comment: "this is normal behaviour"                        Sorry Vladimir, but what I am seeing presented to the server is a leading slash... I am trying to make a change so that the server does not see a leading slash.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. I didn't found any solution. Also browser (chrorme in my case) add leading slash for XHR as well. My opinion that server side should be agnostic to leading/trailing slashes. Like ```/foo/bar/``` and ```foo/bar``` feels like the same URL.

Comment: I agree with the 'should be' statement Vladimir .... but I have a request from a customer that that I am obliged to respond to.   Thank you for looking at this.   Is there anybody else reading this that could weigh in Please?

Comment: Seems chrome implemented it with leading ```/``` https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3

Comment: What’s the problem?  Buggy cgi code that can’t be fixed?  What about a server rewrite rule that strips the leading slash.

Comment: No James, a request from a client.  He refers to needing compatibility with a 'Proxy'.   The only specifics he gives is a request for me to remove the leading slash as described above.